# Why wont the speed for the Viewflipper change?

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to pass the variable from the seek bar to set the seed of a viewflipper into antother activity but I cannot get the speed to change. Am i passing the seek bar value right? Are there special methods to call the variable from a seek bar? Is there any special way to set up intent using the seekbar?

```
public class SlideShow extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide_show);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int progress = intent.getExtras().getInt("progress");
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)this.findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
    viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
    viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(progress);
    viewFlipper.startFlipping();
} }

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

SeekBar seekBar;
int progress;
Button button;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setMax(10);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, SlideShow.class);
    intent.putExtra("progress", progress);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            progress = seekBar.getProgress();
        }
    });

  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View view){
          if (view.getId() == R.id.button){
              startActivity(intent);
          }
  }
});}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating the `progress` extra in the intent. Updating the `progress` variable it's not enough, you need to update the extra again.

```
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    progress = seekBar.getProgress();
    intent.putExtra("progress", progress);
}
```

That would be the quickest solution.

Anyway, I'd say it's better that you create the whole intent in the onClick listener (and remove it from the body of onCreate):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        if (view.getId() == R.id.button){
            final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SlideShow.class);
            intent.putExtra("progress", progress);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: When I try to do that it gives me this error: Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anoymous.android.vew.Vew.OnClickListner, java.lang.Class<com.example.anielloscartozzi.SlideShow

Comment: I've updated the answer, the `this` used in the creation of the Intent was pointing to the OnClickListener, now it points to MainActivity.

Comment: Thanks so much I was trying to get that earlier and you helped a lot. Now how can i update intent if I put it in the OnClick mehtod?

Comment: The intent is created each time you click and will get the most up-to-date `progress` value, as the value is a field in your `MainActivity`.

Comment: @AnielloScartozzi Did my answer solve your issue? If so, please mark it as the solution. Thanks.